# Optimal Solution to a Game With Two Sequences of Bits

Tags: probability, game-theory, puzzle

I was given a nice riddle, and solved it, and I can't tell if my solution is optimal or not.

**The riddle is a follows:**

Two infinite sequences $a_n, b_n$ of bits are randomized. The sequence $a_n$ is shown to you, and the sequence $b_n$ to your friend. Each of you has to guess a number, say $n_1, n_2$, respectively. If $a_{n_2} = b_{n_1}$ you (both) win, otherwise you (both) lose.
Formulate a strategy to win more than 50% of the games.

**I've thought of the following solution**:

Each player guesses the index of the first bit that equals $1$.

There's a probability of $\frac{1}{4^n}$ that both of us guessed the $n$-th index, which will be a win, as both indexes will have the value $1$.
Hence, there's a probability of $\ \sum\frac{1}{4^n} = \frac{1}{3}\ $ that both of us guessed the same index and therefore won.

Otherwise, WLOG I guessed a smaller index ($n_1 < n_2$), and therefore $b_{n_1} = 0$, and $a_{n_2}$ is some random bit. Therefore, If we didn't guess the same index, the probability of us winning is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore this solution gives a winning probability of $\frac{2}{3}$.

**Is this an optimal solution to this question?**

1. Is there a better solution?
2. If not, can someone provide a proof?

Comment: Hello, I don’t know if your solution is optimal but I know it’s generally really hard to prove that a solution to a game like that is optimal. There is no general method because of the possible complexity of the space we’re looking at (for example here functions $f : \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$) but sometimes you can prove optimality by using specificities of the given problem. I think that these problems are rather « riddles » because there is often one astucious solution and you don’t really know why it’s the only (a fortiori). I know another one of that kind if you’re interested !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am interested, please share :)

Comment: Check this link : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem !! As stated in the article, there is a proof for the optimality of the solution for this problem. I’ll let you read it ;) EDIT : the article with solution isn’t free but I found this thread : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31499/100-prisoners-100-boxes-proof-of-optimality

Comment: @hugo_panch Seems interesting, I'll give it a shot before reading the solutions. Thanks! :)